# Getting NULL values after loading data into Hive tables from an online dataset

Tags: hadoop, hive, null, hdfs, hiveql

I am trying to load a data from an online dataset into my hive table using hue interface but I am getting NULL values.

Here's my dataset:

https://www.kaggle.com/psparks/instacart-market-basket-analysis?select=aisles.csv

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AISLES (aisles_id INT, aisles STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Here's how I loaded the data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hadoop/aisles.csv' INTO TABLE aisles;
```

My Workaround, but no go:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
```

Also tried removing `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

This is how I downloaded the data:

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-76-58 ~]$ wget -O aisles.csv "https://www.kaggle.com/psparks/instacart-market-basket-analysis?select=aisles.csv"
--2020-10-14 23:50:06--  https://www.kaggle.com/psparks/instacart-market-basket-analysis?select=aisles.csv
Resolving www.kaggle.com (www.kaggle.com)... 35.244.233.98
Connecting to www.kaggle.com (www.kaggle.com)|35.244.233.98|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘aisles.csv’
```

I checked the location of the table I created this is what it says;

```
hdfs://ip-172-31-76-58.ec2.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse/aisles
```

I tried browsing the directory and see where the file was saved:

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-76-58 ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwt   - arjiesaenz hadoop          0 2020-10-15 00:57 /user/hive/warehouse/aisles
```

So, I tried to change my load script like this;

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hive/warehouse/aisles.csv' INTO TABLE aisles;
```

But I got an error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 6:61 Invalid path ''/user/hive/warehouse/aisles.csv'': No files matching path hdfs://ip-172-31-76-58.ec2.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse/aisles.csv
```

Hopefully someone can help me pinpoint the problem with my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same on my hadoop cluster. The code worked without any issues.
Here's my execution snippet:

```
    hive> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AISLES (aisles_id INT, aisles STRING)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    > LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE
    > tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
OK
Time taken: 0.034 seconds
hive> load data inpath '/user/hirwuser1448/aisles.csv' into table AISLES;
Loading data to table revisit.aisles
Table revisit.aisles stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=2603]
OK
Time taken: 0.183 seconds
hive> select * from AISLES limit 10;
OK
1       prepared soups salads
2       specialty cheeses
3       energy granola bars
4       instant foods
5       marinades meat preparation
6       other
7       packaged meat
8       bakery desserts
9       pasta sauce
10      kitchen supplies
Time taken: 0.038 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)
```

I think you need to cross check if your dataset *aisles.csv* is at the hdfs location and not stored at local directory.

The problem is with your load cmd.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hive/warehouse/aisles.csv' INTO TABLE aisles;
```

I see you tried browsing the dir to see the saved file. Do you see aisles.csv under that dir? If the file's there, then you're giving wrong path in your load cmd else file isn't there at all.

Comment: Hi Ayush, when I downloaded the dataset it just says Saving to: ‘aisles.csv’. Not a complete directory path. I am new to this but this is what I was doing to check the path of the aisles.csv 

hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwt   - arjiesaenz hadoop          0 2020-10-15 00:57 /user/hive/warehouse/aisles

Changed my load script like this but it says no matching file error:

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hive/warehouse/aisles.csv' INTO TABLE aisles;

And I also tried

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hive/warehouse/aisles' INTO TABLE aisles;

Comment: @Tyrell, you're gettng the error because the file isn't there. Just cross verify where you've downloaded the dataset and give that path/aisles.csv in your load cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by downloading the dataset and uploaded it into the Amazon S3 bucket and used the S3 path in the LOAD command.